# Select one row in R, result is a new table

Tags: r, database, select, dataframe, row

I try to select just one row in my data but the result come out in new data and I can't compute the mean of this, because the header is showing. But when I select the column, there is no problem and I can see the result as a value. You can see the result of the code in the photo that y is in data and X is in the value.

```
y=mydata[1,]
X=mydata[,4]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCA8Q.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615450/getting-a-row-from-a-data-frame-as-a-vector-in-r

Answer (score 0):

you should use rowMeans.
When you select a row you are selecting multiple variables and that results in giving you a dataframe.